# how to build a java web service and consuming it in j2me client (with netbeans)

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, java-me

Anyone can give me some guidelines or resources about how to build a java web service and consuming it in j2me client application with Netbeans IDE? (Step-to-step tutorial is appreciated) 
Do I have to write servlet or just normal Java class? How to invoke service from J2me client application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [How to create webservice in java in netbeans](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyRTrccuVAE)
- [Consuming webservice from java-me client](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3H9AI6ru7R8)

Nothing explain this better.

Comment: thank you. it means I don't have to write servlet, just write normal Java class? Servlet is associated with JSP client only?

Comment: And what great tutorials to follow. I've created a ws and a simple client, and point it to ws's wsdl. However, the 2nd video is of low quality, so I'm still unclear about what he typed into the IDE to make things work. Stuck there. Pliz help